# reading a directory in C++ in portable way

Tags: c++

I have a requirement as follows. I have a directory for eg i have /tmp/myFolder

Under "myFolder" i have files whose names as below

```
myFile-N001.txt
myFile-N002.txt
myFile-N003.txt
```

in my application while writing to a file i should write to largest number file in /tmp/myFolder, for eg in above case i should write to myFile-N003.txt.

> The above should be achieved in C++ and in portable way preferably in POSIX way.

Can any one provide simple example on how we can achive this in C++.

Thanks

Comment: are you allowed to use boost::filesystem? That works on POSIX and is portable to other platforms too, eg Windows.

Comment: i am not allowed to use boost.

Comment: To be pedantic:  In C++, there is no portable way to read directories since the specification does not require platforms to have directories.  Many embedded systems do not have directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really two problems in one. I'd use Boost.Filesystem to portably iterate over the files and store them in a `vector` with (**untested**)

```
std::string maxname;
unsigned maxnum = 0;

for (fs::path::iterator i(dir.begin()), end(dir.end()); i != end; ++i) {
    std::string name = i->string();
    unsigned num;
    if (std::sscanf(name.c_str(), "myFile-N%u.txt", &num) == 1
     && num >= maxnum) {
        maxnum = num;
        maxname = name;
    }
}
```

then check whether `maxname` holds the empty string after the loop. If it doesn't, it holds the filename you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy enough to:

- work only on POSIX
- You know the pattern you are looking for

You can use the **`glob()`** function in POSIX to get the list.

You can then use std::max with a custom comparison on the result set with your iterator range being globres.gl_pathv[0], globres.gl_pathv[globres.gl_pathc] and a comparison being something like:

```
bool strless(const char* str1, const char* str2 )
{
   return strcmp( str1, str2 ) < 0;
}
```

although there is most likely something already that does that

The start of the "man" page for glob:

```
   #include <glob.h>

   int glob(const char *pattern, int flags,
            int (*errfunc) (const char *epath, int eerrno),
            glob_t *pglob);

   void globfree(glob_t *pglob);
```

**DESCRIPTION**

The `glob()`  function searches for all the pathnames matching pattern according to the rules used by the shell (see `glob`(7)).  No tilde expansion or parameter substitution
is done; if you want these, use `wordexp`(3).

The `globfree()` function frees the dynamically allocated storage from an earlier call to `glob()`.

The results of a `glob()` call are stored in the structure pointed to by pglob.  This structure is of type `glob_t` (declared in `<glob.h>`) and includes the following elements
defined by POSIX.2 (more may be present as an extension):

```
 typedef struct 
 {
     size_t   gl_pathc;    /* Count of paths matched so far  */
     char   **gl_pathv;    /* List of matched pathnames.  */
     size_t   gl_offs;     /* Slots to reserve in gl_pathv.  */
 } glob_t;
```

There was a [discussion](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2004/10/index.php) in October 2004 about bringing glob into boost I don't think it ever got implemented:

Answer (score 2):

There's code for retrieving the list of files from a directory in a POSIX-compliant way [here](http://www.mdawson.net/misc/readDirectory.php).

You could build on that by sorting the resulting array and popping the last element off. That would be the file you want to find.

Comment: The MinGW Runtime is public domain and offers a layer of compatibility to this method. So it's feasible for Win32, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) to achieve this.